# Breakpoints not active in VS Code Node.js Remote Debugging on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I've followed the process in this article
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/remote-debugging

While a debug session seems to have started, I cannot set or use any breakpoints.

Node.js in an App Service

I can stream logs.
I tried to set a breakpoint on the files that show up in the Azure Explorer as well as the files that I work on.
I keep getting an Unbound breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Created Node JS App and deployed to `Azure Linux App Service`.

- Followed the same steps from the provided document to `Enable Remote Debugging`.

[image]

- Even I got the same `Unbound breakpoint` message.

[image]

- In `Azure Portal` => `App Service` => `Configuration` =>check `Remote debugging`  Under Debugging section.

[image]

- To cross check that I have changed the Runtime stack to `.NET` and tried to `Enable Remote debugging` from `VSCode`.Got the below error.

[image]

- It clearly says that `Remote Debugging` option is available for `NodeJS Azure Linux App`.
- Again, updated the Runtime stack back to `NODE`.

Thanks [@Kenneth](https://kenneth.io/post/introducing-remote-debugging-of-nodejs-apps-on-azure-app-service-from-vs-code-in-public-preview) for the configuration steps.

Tried to change few configurations as mentioned in the Document.

In `VSCode` => `File` => `Preferences` => `Settings` =>In search box search with `appservice` keyword.

[image]

We will get an option to edit `settings.json` file.

[image]

- In `settings.json`, add the below line of code

```cs
"appService.enableRemoteDebugging":true
```

- In `Package.json` change the `scripts` setting as below.

```cs
"scripts": {
"start": "node ./bin/www",
"start\\_azure\\_debug": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:$APPSVC\\_TUNNEL\\_PORT index.js"
},
```

- In `Azure Portal` => Your `Azure App Service` => `Configuration` =>`General settings`, add the `npm run start_azure_debug` as startup command.

[image]

- Now try to debug from `VSCode` .
- Getting Timeout Exception.
  [image]

There might be some issue with `Remote Debugging`,`MS Support` request may be required.

Comment: Great details @Harshitha. Hope MS Support picks this up